# Creating an infinite loop with a non blocking keyboard input exit

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am trying to create an infinite loop that continues until there is any keyboard input. From what I can find online, a good way to do this is by using parallel threads. My problem is that i cant seem to get my threads running in parallel. My code is made from what i can understand in other questions. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried to define each thread's process in separate functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int n=0, a=0;

void *check(int *q){
    *q = getchar();
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *loop(int q){
    while(1){
        printf("%d\n", q++);
        if(a!=0)
            break;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void){
    printf("start program\n");
    pthread_t threads[2];

    pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, check(&a), (void *) a);
    printf("start loop\n");
    pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, loop(n), (void *) n);
    printf("end program\n");
}'
```

Comment: If by "keyboard input" you mean standard input, you could use `select` or `poll` with a timeout of 0.

Comment: Even if this code was correct (and it silently passes compilation because you decided to make all your functions return a `void*`, which you don't even return from these functions), you would end up with 3 threads: 1 foreground one running the `main` function, and 2 background threads running `check` and `loop` functions. And the main thread doesn't wait for background threads. Make your functions `void`, pass the actual *function* as a parameter to `pthread_create`, and either: 1) create only a single thread for the background task and wait for keypress inside main, or 2) use `pthread_join`.

Answer (score 1):

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, check(&a), (void *) a);

pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, loop(n), (void *) n);
```

Thats undefined behaviour, you are supposed to pass function pointers but instead you are calling those thread functions, the return values of those functions will be treated as function pointers likely to result in undefined behaviour
You should created threads as:

```
pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, check, (void *) NULL);

pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, loop, (void *) NULL);
```

`n` and `a` are globals so you wont need to pass them in thread functions you can access them directly

Comment: 3rd parameter has to be function pointer of thread handler, which I pointed in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Following is Syntax for  pthread_create `int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);`

As per syntax third argument should be function pointer of type void *(*start_routine) (void *). Instead you done function call with no return value.

Also please use pthread_join to prevent main thread sop before child threads